# MAC address from port

Tags: networking, mac-address

I am new to networking so excuse if this is a straightforward question.

Is there a way to get the MAC address of a port on a Xyplex router?

Have tried Sh Mac-add but command not  recognised.

Thanks

Comment: can u provide specific model of the router ?

Comment: Sure I believe it's a terminal server: N-Base Xyplex Max Server 1640

Comment: If you know the IP address of this port, ping it from any host on the same subnet. then check the arp table on the host that you made the ping : ie. C:\>ping 1.2.3.4 then C:\>arp -a

Comment: Xyplex>> SHOW NODES [name] STATUS

Comment: @chenchuk that worked cheers, I pinged the Xyplex IP address and it gave me a list of IP address and corresponding MACs, how can I trace each Mac now back to a port ?

Comment: what do you mean "back to a port" ? the ping process start with ARP request, asking who (which host hold that IP) and the replying host (Xyplex) will reply with its MAC (thats all happens BEFORE the first ping, ping is not necessary, we just triggering an ARP request). searching the ARP table (arp -a) will show Xyplex-IP <---> Xyplex MAC.

Comment: Maybe what I am asking does not make sense but I'll try again- I got the ARP table when I ping the Xyplex ter server IP address, . The table contains IP addresses and corresponding MAC addressees, I am assuming the devices with these MAC address are connecting to various ports in the Xyplex terminal server. So is it possible to see which device is connected to which port on try terminal server?

Comment: I think you mix something here ... Xyplex is terminal-server and not ethernet-switch ( both devices have RJ-45 connectors, but is different protocol). on ethernet-switch , the connected hosts are ETHERNET with MAC-ADDRESS and IP on top of those . on a terminal-server the connected hosts are ASYNC terminals and no IP at all ( unless you use some other protocol for ip as SLIP/PPP ) anyway there is no MAC-ADDRESS for those since its not ETHERNET card.

Comment: Ok, in Xyplex if I call show port <number> I get a ' preferred ip address ' for the port. If I ping this address and call arp - a I get then arp table. So what do these IP addresses - macs represent ? I get same arp table if I ping the Xyplex terminal server address

Comment: Its difficult without a proper diagram. keep in mind that MAC address available in ETHERNET protocol, there is no MAC address for ASYNC ports. ( IP can work but over SLIP or over PPP ), i suggest a proper diagram and explain what u are trying to achieve.

Comment: Unfortunately no diagrams etc it's an old system with no records. Could the Xyplex TS be configured as a switch ? If so can we link a port with a MAC and IP address of a contented device?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92223/discussion-between-chenchuk-and-dancingbush).

Comment: @chenchuk thanks  for all try help it's clearer now